# How to hide duplicate button under action of Sale order

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11

I want to hide `Duplicate` button located under `action` of `sale order`. Is there any possible way to hide this button?

I can restrict the users by adding `Warning` in python but I want to hide it in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Inherit sale order form view and then add attribute `duplicate='false'`. Following is the code:

```
     <record id="view_order_form_duplicate" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">sale.order.form.duplicate</field>
         <field name="model">sale.order</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="duplicate">false</attribute>
            </xpath>
         </field>
     </record>
```

You can also add security group if you want to hide it for some specific users.

```
    <record id="view_order_form_duplicate" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">sale.order.form.duplicate</field>
         <field name="model">sale.order</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
         <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('module_name.group_name')])]"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="duplicate">false</attribute>
            </xpath>
         </field>
     </record>
```

This code works for me.